# error: array type has incomplete element type - already defined structs

Tags: c

```
extern  const   struct  ss_type     ss_table    [MAX_CLASS];
extern  const   struct  ss_group_type   ss_group_table  [MAX_GROUPS];
```

merc.h:4430:30: error: array type has incomplete element type
merc.h:4431:35: error: array type has incomplete element type

Working on a pet project and am completely stumped on this one. I don't really have an idea of why this error would reflect these lines. My best guess would be that the compiler can't make sense of what ss_table, ss_type, ss_group_table, and ss_group_type are.

However, ss_table and ss_type are defined

```
const struct ss_type    ss_table [MAX_CLASS] =  {   {   /* FALSE */  
"",     
{0},    
{0},    
{NULL}  
},
```

So are ss_group_table and ss_group_type

```
const struct ss_group_type  ss_group_table [MAX_GROUPS] = 
{
  /* NONE: FALSE return 0 */
  {"", 0,
   {
     {NULL, 0, 0,   {NULL},    {NULL}  }
   }
  },
```

which puts me at a loss for how to resolve this error.

Comment: Which line exactly does the error point to?

Comment: Your assessment would be a good guess, considering "incomplete element type" is about as clear as a compiler can get in saying I have no clue what X is. Is `struct ss_type` defined anywhere *above*, or included *before*, the `extern` that is giving you problems? Look at your code.

Comment: I tried to shorten as much as possible, but all of this is located across several thousand lines of code and 3 different files. I checked to make sure the relevant files were included, and they are. To my knowledge, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, type has only be forward-declared, but not been specified. At least you didn't give us any. A resl definition like

```
struct toto {
  double hei;
};
```

must be visible.

Such `struct` definitions should be put in a header file `.h` and be included in `.c` files (co called compilation units) to make the definitions visible.

Comment: `struct ss_group_type{
  char* name;     
  sh_int skills;     
  struct ss_info_type ss_info[MAX_GROUP_SKILL]; 
}; 

 struct ss_type{
  char*  name;
  sh_int level[MAX_SELECT]; 
  sh_int picks[MAX_SELECT]; 
  char*  group[MAX_SELECT]; `

That better? It's early for me, musta copied the wrong bit.

Comment: That would be better, but your compilers tells you that this is not visible at the point where it complains.

Comment: So I should move it from the file it's referencing to the file that's throwing the error and then remove the extra definition from the referenced file?

Answer (score 0):

If the type is incomplete, it means that the it has been forward-declared, but has not yet been declared fully.

For example, the following compiles:

```
struct S1 {};
struct S1 arr1[10];
```

whereas the following doesn't:

```
struct S2;
struct S2 arr2[10]; /* error: array type has incomplete element type */
struct S2 {};
```